# How to create new branch in a remote?

Tags: git, version-control

I have made a mistake with my git branch workflow

I have the following local and remote branches setup:

```
master -> origin/master
iteration5 -> origin/iteration5
iteration9 -> origin/iteration5
```

I need the upstream on my local branch (`iteration9`) to be set to a remote branch called `origin/iteration9`.

Given the current state of my repo, how can I create a remote branch called `iteration9` based off of my local branch `iteration9`, if it is already pointing to an old remote branch (`origin/iteration5`)

Comment: Your setup is a bit difficult to parse.  Can you edit your post to make it clearer?

Comment: @alexbclay I forgot line breaks. It should be more clear now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove it with

```
git branch --unset-upstream iteration9
```

then reset it by pushing to origin with the `--set-upstream` flag:

```
git push --set-upstream origin iteration9
```

or you can set it with this command if the remote branch already exists:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/iteration9
```